# Error GoogleSignIn comand ionic capacitor build

Tags: angular

hello I’ve been having this error for several days in order to copy my app in ios when I run the command in ionic : ionic capacitor build, and choose the IOS platform I get the following error that I don’t know how to solve.

```
[capacitor] ✖ Updating iOS native dependencies with pod install - failed!
[capacitor] ✖ update ios - failed!
[capacitor] [error] Analyzing dependencies
[capacitor]         [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleSignIn":
[capacitor]         In Podfile:
[capacitor]         CodetrixStudioCapacitorGoogleAuth (from `../../node_modules/@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
[capacitor]         GoogleSignIn (~> 6.0.1)
[capacitor]         
[capacitor]         CordovaPluginsStatic (from `../capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins`) was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
[capacitor]         GoogleSignIn (~> 5.0.2)
[capacitor]         
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
```

Please, has anyone had this problem, how can I solve this? I’m stuck here for several days and I don’t know what to do or how to get out, I can’t find much on google. thanks.

I have tried changing the ios version in the podfile, from 13 to the previous ones up to 10 and nothing works.
My computer is a Imac 2013 SO Catalina 10.15.7

My package.json:

```
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~14.0.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/call-number": "^5.39.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/camera": "^5.39.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^5.39.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/deeplinks": "^5.39.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/file": "^5.39.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/geolocation": "^5.39.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/google-plus": "^5.39.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser": "^5.39.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/media": "^5.39.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/media-capture": "^5.39.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/onesignal": "^5.39.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/social-sharing": "^5.45.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/stripe": "^5.39.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^4.0.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "^4.0.0",
    "@capacitor/camera": "^4.0.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@capacitor/device": "^4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^4.0.0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^4.4.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^4.0.0",
    "@capacitor/preferences": "^4.0.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^4.0.0",
    "@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth": "^3.2.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.0.0",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^8.5.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-media-capture": "^3.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-stripe": "^1.5.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^6.0.3",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^9.6.7",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.27",
    "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": "^1.0.24",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-payment-card": "0.0.8",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-pipes": "^3.0.0",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "rxfire": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.4",
    "swiper": "^8.1.6",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~14.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.182",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "cordova-res": "^0.15.4",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.18.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.2.8
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.2.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 14.0.7
   @angular/cli                  : 14.0.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 5.0.3

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 4.2.0
   @capacitor/android : 4.2.0
   @capacitor/core    : 4.4.0
   @capacitor/ios     : 4.4.0

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.4
   native-run (update available: 1.7.1) : 1.7.0

System:

   NodeJS : v16.17.0 (/Users/ivanpala/.nvm/versions/node/v16.17.0/bin/node)
   npm    : 8.19.2
   OS     : macOS Catalina
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! There are few problems wih your question. 1) Paste here and format it using the code tag {} for code (CTRL-K) like `session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)` ; 2) do provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us help you;  3) alternatively, if you think your error is not code related, provide all setup, installation and software versions that you are using;

Comment: ok thanks I will try to edit well, but do you know anything about why I can have this error?